# How to conceal a computer in operation with a separate logon password?

Tags: passwords

Goal: Disallow people physically near the computer to see its operations.

No password to start the computer.
But, I'd like to conceal the screen after startup and all programs loaded. 
Because of the administrator being away from the location of the physical computer.
The screen should lock (while applications are running in the background).

Comment: What is the OS and version of the computer?

Comment: Could you clarify: Do you mean the admin is remotely starting a machine physically located somewhere else, and you don't want the screen to show anything until he gets there and enters a password?

Comment: Isn't that the idea behind, well, a server?

Comment: You could always take away the monitor ;)

Comment: Yes Worse Doughnut. I want the local physical people to be able to start up the screen, but never see the operation and data by plugging in a screen.                                                                                                                                                                                                                       @ DEER HUNTER Yes almost like a SERVER, but I want to explore alternatives with LAN set up not paying server fees.

Comment: @user3096988: What do you mean by "server fees"? Sorry if the question may sound basic (remember I don't know you) but you are conscious that a *server* is just a machine providing a set of *services*. Any computer in your LAN can be used as a server.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done with RDP and Windows 10 Pro. Just set it up normally, and then you connect via RDP. There will then be 2 sessions on the computer, one console, that is visible to the local user, and one remote RDP session, that is only visible to the administrator.

The administrator session can be taken over from the local console, but only if you know the administrator password.